# What is cpplink

Tags: c++, manpage

I am trying to get my hands on a C++ library called dislin using ubuntu 14.04. The test provided by the developers is simply:

```
cpplink -c exa_cpp
```

And it compiles correctly. I've also built another script that compiles using the cpplink command. But when I type:

```
man cpplink
```

I get:

```
No manual entry for cpplink
```

And I am not able to compile this library using my g++ compiler which I just started to understand. So I am thinking some info on cpplink would help. I tried google and normal search routes but it seems like the name is just too common for search engines.

Comment: I might also add that there is no 'cpplink' file in my /usr/bin folder.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/dislin-users/f4FICMFpD5Y

Comment: `which cpplink` shows..?

Comment: Thanks to you both. Your comments helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cpplink is a bash script located at $DISLIN/bin. The script links the necessary libraries to the g++ precompiler in order to get the program running and compiled. For more information you should only type

```
cpplink
```

Which outputs to:

```
/******************************************************************/
/**                    C P P L I N K                             **/
/**                                                              **/
/** CPPLINK links C++ programs using DISLIN routines.            **/
/**                                                              **/
/** Command:    cpplink    [option]     main                     **/
/**                                                              **/
/** option      is an optional  parameter  that can  have one of **/
/**             the following values:                            **/
/**        -c   for compiling programs before linking            **/
/**        -r   for running programs after linking               **/
/**        -a   for compiling, linking and running programs.     **/
/**                                                              **/
/** main        is the name of the main program or may be in the **/
/**             form   'main obj lib'   where obj is  a field of **/
/**             object files and lib a  field of library  files. **/
/**             Several files must be separated by blanks.       **/
/**             A file  'main'  will be created after linking.   **/
/**                                                              **/
/** Example:    cpplink  -a  test mylib.a                        **/
/******************************************************************/
```